# Issue when navigating from one form to another when second form has Picker control

Tags: codenameone

In my App, While navigating from one form to another, I found an issue with both android and IOS debug build. This will happen only when second form contains any type of Picker control. I have added logic to navigating to second form on click of a button on the first form. So now when I click the button, Picker control of the  second form open up on first form instead of navigating to second form. Second form will appear only after I made the selection on Picker Control. This issue is happening on bother android and IOS builds. Please advise if any one encounter similar issue with recent debug builds.

This happens only when Picker is first control on the form.

**Code used for Picker:**

```
Picker firstAppForm = new Picker();
String[] options = {"Tabbed Menu", "My Schedule "};
firstAppForm.setStrings(options);
firstAppForm.setUIID("TextField");
firstAppForm.setAutoSizeMode(true);
```

Comment: I don't understand this description. Pickers never navigated to a different form? What did you do in terms of code? Can you add screenshots/video?

Comment: Sure Shai. When I navigate from one form to another form, if the second form has Picker control, Picker opens on current form and second form will be loaded only after I made any selection in the Picker control. Does this make any sense?

Comment: I'm getting this behaviour as well, it stops occurring if I set the picker to use the lightweight popup mode to true.

Comment: I found a bug in the lightweight picker by the way, I have a dialog with two pickers in a scrollable Boxlayout Y Container and when I click the first one, it doesn't popup until I click on the second picker and then it continues to work normally.

Comment: Thank You Mario for letting us know.

Comment: @Mario - Even in the lightweight mode, I do encounter same issue as you. Did you find any work around for it? Please advise

Comment: These are related to the new focus traversal logic we introduced https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2419#issuecomment-393521572 we'll try to address this

Comment: Thank you Shai for the update. AS this is one of the critical functionality for our App, do you know when can we expect the fix ? Please advise.

Comment: Hey guys, hope this help with pin pointing the cause of the bugs mentioned above. 
This first two videos are related to the lightweight picker:
- [https://youtu.be/GSEe7jFcDWU](https://youtu.be/GSEe7jFcDWU)  (the first picker doesn't popup upon opening the dialog, only after having selected the second picker)
- [https://youtu.be/bIYQfwZE4Vw](https://youtu.be/bIYQfwZE4Vw) 

This last video is related to the native picker, the first picker pops up upon before the dialog (new form) has been shown.
- [https://youtu.be/728wmcqxURs](https://youtu.be/728wmcqxURs)

Comment: @ShaiAlmog where you guys able to pinpoint the cause of this bug? if so, will there be a solution posted soon? this bug is unfortunately causing quite some trouble to us.

Comment: AFAIK it was already fixed and should be a part of tomorrows update

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce it and wasn't able to but I did run into a null pointer exception related to the native picker which might be the underlying cause of this.

I've pushed out a fix that should be available now so if you send a new build this will hopefully be resolved.

Comment: Hi Shai, I have given another build just now and still the issue exists and this is now happening on IOS builds as well. Please advise.

Comment: Shai, I have updated the screenshots to provide more information about this issue. Please advise.

Comment: This happens only when Picker is first control on the second form.

Answer (score 0):

as a reference, I've published three videos to help illustrate the current problems I'm facing and probably @Chris L as well, maybe this aid in finding out the root of the problem. The links can be found as a comment to the initial publication.

Comment: Thank You Mario for the videos to explain the issue.